# how to config spring cloud hystrix semaphore max concurrent

Tags: spring-cloud, hystrix

The concurrent test failed and the logs says:

com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: community-serviceRibbonCommand could not acquire a semaphore for execution and no fallback available.

I read the source code. It seems that it's controlled by executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests.

My question is how to increase executionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests?

Comment: any luck with `execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests` ?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Setter you can

```
    public class HystrixCommandInstance extends HystrixCommand<>        
      public HystrixCommandInstance() {
          super(Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory.asKey("SomeGroupName"))
          .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(HystrixCommandProperties.Setter()
                 .withExecutionIsolationSemaphoreMaxConcurrentRequests(200)));
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `@HystrixCommand` annotation, you can specify `commandProperties()` to configure the command.

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "fallbackMethod",
            commandProperties = {
                    @HystrixProperty(name = "execution.isolation.semaphore.maxConcurrentRequests", value = "15")
             })
```